# How to prefix every blog slug with "new-" using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web-development-server

I want to add "new" to every blog URL slug.

For example, if someone visits `https://www.example.com/blog/post-one` it will redirect to `https://www.example.com/blog/new-post-one`.

Comment: You should include the contents of your existing `.htaccess` file and the directives you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of the root `.htaccess` file try the following using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect "/blog/<post-title>" to "/blog/new-<post-title>"
RewriteRule ^(blog)/(?!new-)([\w-]+)$ /$1/new-$2 [R=302,L]
```

This assumes `<post-title>` consists of only the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` (underscore) and `-` (hyphen)

`(?!new-)` - this is a *negative lookahead* that asserts that the `<post-title>` does not already start with `new-`. Otherwise we would get an endless redirect loop.

You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive if it already occurs (later) in the file.